# How do you interpret "grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(800px, 3fr) 1fr;"?

Tags: html, css, web

What does "grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr;" mean? I understand the 1fr at the beginning and end but I am confused about what "auto minmax(600px, 3fr)" does.

HTML:

```
        <a class="logo" href="index-new.html"><img src="images/logo-b.png" alt="logo"></a>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle">
        <nav>
            <hr/>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a> </li>
                <li><a href="assets/Resume_V7.pdf" target="_blank">Resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <label for="nav-toggle" class="nav-toggle-label"><span></span></label>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
    .logo {
        grid-column: 2 / 3;
    }
    nav {
        grid-column: 3 / 4;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }

    ...

    header {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr auto minmax(600px, 3fr) 1fr; /* Meaning? */
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minmax(600px, 3fr)` means the column size will be at minimum `600px`, or up to a maximum of `3fr`

`auto` is setting the size of a different column and is unrelated to `minmax` in this situation.

See more about the minmax function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax

Comment: You're welcome! It looks like you are new to the site. There's no obligation, but if a response answers your question, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it as the correct answer. This will help future users identify that a solution has been found. Enjoy the site!